# How to append a string resource into a TextView and apply gravity to it Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, gravity

I have a textView that I am adding string resource using Reflextion.

```
fun reflexionAtWork(myCar : String) : Int{    
           val res = R.string::class.java
           val field = res.getField(numStrofa)
           val drawableId = field.getInt(null)
           return drawableId
}
```

I can use this function and append strings to my textView. I was wondering if anybody here can help me center certain strings.

Here is how I call this function in my program.

```
myTextView.append(getString(reflexionAtWork("car" + model + "_year" + index)))
myTextView.append(getString(reflexionAtWork("parts" + number + "_year")))
```

Is there a way to center the second appended string. I understand that if I do myTextView.gravity = Gravity.center, the whole thing will be centered. (I tried that).

I also tried making the first append left and center every other time (this is used in loop).

I tried this(did not work)

```
myTextView.gravity = Gravity.left
 myTextView.append(getString(reflexionAtWork("car" + model + "_year" + index)))
 myTextView.gravity = Gravity.center
 myTextView.append(getString(reflexionAtWork("parts" + number + "_year")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to split `myTextView` into multiple text fields; one left-aligned, one centered.  I'm not sure how feasible this will be with your text values, but that way you can have proper formatting on each field.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a layout called Constraintlayouts. You can make it automatically space your text views depending on how much text is inside them. You can link the views, set to wrap content, set size to ratio of screen, weighted, by percent,  and many other options to make it work exactly like your wanting.

Specifically I would look into making the Textviews into chains then taking your needs from there. Hope that helps at least get you started.